# Linear Algebra projection problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't even know where to begin with this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Solve aTa(x-hat) = aTb to show that x-hat is the mean of the b's

(T is transpose)

b = (b1, ..., bm)
a = (1, ..., 1)
We solve m equations ax = b in 1 unknown (by least squares)

Thanks!!

Comment: Surely that's not what the original problem statement said. Can you add the full statement, give some context, and explain what you've tried?

Comment: You might try a little bit harder with the formatting?

Comment: Sorry, I put more information into the original post now.